# What is stale indexing?

Tags: nosql, ravendb, ravendb-studio

I've Started learning `RavenDb`, often I used to come across **"stale indexing"**, couldn't find a better understanding of it.  I tried documentation, but couldn't capture an easy way to grasp the point.

When I used `SQL`, I haven't heard anything about stale indexing.  Is it special in **`no SQL`** databases?

**NOTE:** I haven't added the code, since my base knowledge of `RavenDb` is completely zero.

Can anyone point me in the *right direction*. It would be really helpful if someone give a *real case scenario of using stale indexing*.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is not a good fit for StackOverflow.  I see you already asked in the RavenDB Google Group.

Comment: I just Googled 'stale indexes' and the 1st result is a RavenDB page describing what stale indexes are.

Answer (score 2):

Many noSQL databases compromise consistency for speed, and hence allow e. g. the index to be a bit out of synch during data updates. It will be [eventually consistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency).